# How to use multiple statements inside cond?

Tags: scheme, racket

For example I have the following code, I define a variable `v1` then check the value of `v1`. If `v1 == 1`, I want to `(print-list q2)` and read another input and store to `v2`, something like this: `(define v2 (read))`.

```
(define v1 (read))
(cond
  [(null? v1) (printf "No input..\n")]
  [(= v1 1) (print-list q2)]
```

How do I achieve my solution above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write more than one expression after a `cond`'s condition:

```
(define v1 (read))

(cond
  [(null? v1) (printf "No input..\n")]
  [(= v1 1)
   (define v2 (read))
   (print-list q2)]
  [else (error "Unexpected value")])
```

Of course, the above will only work if `print-list` and `q2` were previously defined, but it illustrates the general idea of what you want to do. Just remember that although all expressions after the condition will be executed sequentially, only the value of the last expression will be returned, which in this example is `(print-list q2)`.

Comment: @Bun Note that the scope of the `v2` only exist within the `cond` term and that `define` does not modify an already existing variable so it might not do what you want. `set!` modifies.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use recursion to read repeatedly:

```
(define (f)
  (let loop ((v (read)))
    (cond [(= 0 v) "End."]
          [(= 1 v) (println '(a b c))]
          ; [.. other options ..]
          [else
           (println '(1 2 3))
           (loop (read))])))
```

Testing:

```
(f)

1
'(a b c)
0
"End."
>
```